# Turn off rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, swift3, orientation

trying to turn off that user can't change orientation..

I have my view in landscape and it must be in landscaped so I'm doing it this way

```
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

And also with this that user can't change rotation

```
    private func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
    }
    private func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

**The problem is that it isn' t working. I have after pushing landscaped but I'm still can rotate it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From swift 3 [`shouldAutorotate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621419-shouldautorotate) and [`supportedInterfaceOrientations`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations) is `property` not `method`, so you need to add it like this.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
     return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
}
```

Comment: @patrikbelis Welcome mate :)